# UISearchController appears behind NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show the UISearchController by tapping on the UIBarButtonItem. But the SearchBar appears behind the NavigationBar. If I set definesPresentationContext = false, then the SearchBar appears above the NavigationBar, but the transitions don't work.

```
    @IBAction func searchButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        searchResultsController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultsController") as? SearchResultsController
        searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .words
        definesPresentationContext = true
        present(searchController, animated: true)
    }
```

[Before BarButtonItem tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ7TF.png)

[After BarButtonItem tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZd2g.png)

[View UI Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbIG9.png)

[Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMMja.png)

`searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` solve this problem, but I need the navigation bar to not be hidden

**UPDATE:**

Inserting the SearchBar inside the Navigation Bar is not suitable for my app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGegh.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableViewController` then you can do the following:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Then, you need to assign this `searchController` to `navigationItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Now `searchbar` is going to appear when you pull the tableview and will look this way:

[image]

If you want to keep the search bar permanently, then do this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Comment: I need to display the searchbar at front of viewcontroller when the button is tapped like iOS Calendar app

Comment: In the situation I described it will get hidden too when you scroll, and appear only if you pull the tableview. Or do you want it to appear on a specific button tap exclusively?

Comment: Yes, I want in to appear on button tap

Comment: You can assign `self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController` on your button tap. That will do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for my app
https://imgur.com/a/74e5sSk